# xuggler error -  "cannot find symbol : class VideoImage" - what am i missing?

Tags: java, video-streaming, xuggle

I am using **xuggler** to play video files  from my code and the following is a snippet from the main code:

This snippet produces an error :

```
 //The window we'll draw the video on.

private static VideoImage mScreen = null;

private static void updateJavaWindow(BufferedImage javaImage)
{
  mScreen.setImage(javaImage);
}

// Opens a Swing window on screen.

 private static void openJavaWindow()
 {
    mScreen = new VideoImage();
 }
```

The error that i get is : `cannot find symbol : class VideoImage`

The header files used are :

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Global;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IContainer;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPacket;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IPixelFormat;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStream;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IStreamCoder;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.ICodec;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoPicture;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.IVideoResampler;
import com.xuggle.xuggler.Utils;
```

Am i missing in some import statement ? If not , here are the libraries i am using apart from JDK :

[image]

**What is the reason i am getting that error ?**

Comment: I don't see you importing anything called VideoImage...

Comment: where is the VideoImage class ? I dont see it in the list of imports.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[VideoImage Javadoc](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/demos/VideoImage.html)

You are not importing the right class.

```
com.xuggle.xuggler.demos.VideoImage
```

It seems like you are already using an IDE. It should automatically tell you what import you are missing if the correct library is in the build path.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the VideoImage class.